# Symfony SonataNotificationBundle configuration

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata

Sorry if the question is stupid, I'm pretty new to Symfony. After installation the bundle fillowing the [oficial documentation](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/notification/3-x/doc/reference/installation.html) I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to
>   load class "ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle" from namespace
>   "Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle". Did you forget a "use"
>   statement for another namespace? in
>   C:\OpenServer\domains\tdserebro\app\AppKernel.php:41

The line AppKernel.php#41 is:

```
new Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\ApplicationSonataNotificationBundle(),
```

What does that want me to "use"? There wasn't anything like that in the documentation. 
In case that is important, the class itself stored in app\Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle\ directory(as default). Symfony version is 2.8

Comment: It does not recognize the new bundle, the autoloader failed to load it probably because it can find it in the vendor directory. You should check it does exist. Then `rm -rf app/cache/* && rm -rf app/logs/*` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default autoload configuration expects your class `Application\Sonata\NotificationBundle` to be in *src/Application/Sonata/NotificationBundle/* not under *app/*.

Either reconfigure your autoloader (you can do that in composer.json), or move your files under *src/*.